# How to save Entity with related Null Object with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I want to implement **Null Object pattern** for Hibernate Entity.

Let's assume we have `Person` entity with `Address` field. In one case Address of Person must be defined in other may not be defined.

```
@Entity
class Person {

    String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Address.class)
    IAddress address;

    public Person(String name, IAddress address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
}

interface IAddress {

    String getCity();

    String getStreet();
}

@Entity
class Address implements IAddress {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String city;

    private String street;

    public Address(String city, String street) {
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
}

class NullObjectAddress implements IAddress {

    @Override
    public String getCity() {
        return "London";
    }

    @Override
    public String getStreet() {
        return "Baker street";
    }
}
```

I try to save Person

```
Person per1 = new Person("Jhon Doe", new Address("Huge village", "main street"));
personRepository.save(per1); //that`s ok

Person per2 = new Person("Jhon Doe", new NullObjectAddress());
personRepository.save(per2); //throws exception
```

Exception is:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private Address.id] by reflection for persistent property [Person#id] : NullObjectAddress@3638120f; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Int Person.id] by reflection for persistent property [Person#id] : NullObjectAddress@3638120f

Comment: here's an idea; just set the `address` field to null ... like you would in normal Java. Can't your JPA provider cope with that? Seems that it insists it has to be of the "targetEntity" type, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach would be to use `null` for field value and deal with null objects in getters and setters:

```
@Entity
class Person {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Address.class)
    IAddress address;

    public Person(String name, IAddress address) {
        this.name = name;
        setAddress(address);
    }

    public IAddress getAddress() {
        return address == null ? NullObjectAddress.INSTANCE : address;
    }

    public void setAddress(IAddress address) {
        this.address = address instanceof NullObjectAddress ? null : address;
    }
}
```

However, you would still need to treat it as nullable in JPQL/HQL queries, e.g. you would need to use `address is (not) null` rather than `address = :address` with parameter `:address` having the value of a `NullObjectAddress` instance.